# ArcGIS Pro Python Labelling Expression does not update labels

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, labeling, python-parser

I am trying to alter the size of labels around a point layer using a python if/elif expression. The expression is valid but nothing changes when I apply the expression. Below I have included the code and the attribute table I am working from.

```
def FindLabel ( [TEXT_SIZE], [TEXTSTRING] ):
    if [TEXT_SIZE] == 0.3:
        return "<FNT size= '24'>" + [TEXTSTRING] + "</FNT>"
    elif [TEXT_SIZE] == 0.2:
        return "<FNT size = '18'>" + [TEXTSTRING] + "</FNT>"
    else:
        return "<FNT size = '10'>" + [TEXTSTRING] + "</FNT>"
```

[image]

I'm sure this has a simple solution but I can't seem to get the desired display.

Comment: Comparison of floating point values can be tricky. I'm not sure if it's the problem here, but perhaps the values shown as `0.3` is actually `0.2999999999`. You may need to apply a certain precision, e.g. `abs([TEXT_SIZE] - 0.3) < 0.01` or `round([TEXT_SIZE] * 10) == 3`

Comment: Label engine treats all variables as text. So use ts = float(text) and use it everywhere